# Edit a php file with a php file name config.php

Tags: php, html

I want to create a file in php named config.php with some string similar to this:

```
$this->name = 'Example';
```

And in the file index.php a string like this:

```
<title><?php echo $this->name; ?></title>
```

I've see this in another site but i don't know how this works, can someone help me? Thank you very much!

I try this:

config.php

```
    <?php

final class Settings {
    public static $TRUE = "1", $FALSE = "0";

    public function __construct($connect = true) {
        $this->name = 'Example';
    }


   }
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $this->name; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're probably looking for something like [`require_once()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Comment: Yes but how can i do that, i'm not expert in php

Comment: Read the manual, learn, make an attempt, then if you're still having trouble, update your question with what you tried, what the desired result it, what the actual (undesired) result is, and what debugging you've done to try to solve it yourself.

Comment: I've already try to do this, i try to find that

Comment: If you've already tried something, then do the second part of what I said in my last comment.  Otherwise, you're probably out of luck here.  Consider hiring someone or or taking some classes.

Comment: Updated but i don't know how to connect this 2 file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a reference from [here](https://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete)

```
$my_file = 'config.php';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data = 'This is the data';
fwrite($handle, $data);
```

Comment: Where i insert this?

Comment: @Santosh Kumar, based on the title, I agree with this answer, but based on the question, I believe OP is asking more in line with what Patrick Q commented above.